Fujitsu UH-X overheating since fans no longer spin up after upgrading to 24.04
Laptop: Fujitsu UH-X with 12th Gen Intel Core i5-1235U
Upgraded from 23.04 to 24.04 and fans have stopped working since. CPU cores' temperatures reach upwards of 70 degrees Celsius at times with no fan activity whatsoever.
Fans are not faulty since this problem is non-existent when I boot into Windows (or even the BIOS), and they ramp up as necessary with no issues.
sensors gives me this:
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +34.0°C  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +56.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +82.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +56.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +61.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +70.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 8:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 9:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 10:       +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 11:       +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 12:       +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 13:       +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 14:       +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 15:       +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

CMB1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          16.65 V  
curr1:       924.00 mA 

A few other threads suggested using pwmconfig to configure fan speed, but I couldn't get it to work. The command gives me this:
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

The fan curve is correctly configured in the BIOS (set to Normal out of the two options: Normal and Silent).
I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

No you're right, I didn't transition directly to 24.04. I went from 23.04 > 23.10 > 24.04, just didn't realise that's an important detail.
